# How do I retrieve an image that I saved in a temporary location

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an iOS application where have a view controller where the user can access their camera or library to load up a picture. I am trying to create a temporary copy of this to load into another UIImageView within another view controller. I am able to save the file (at least it looks so in a NSLog, but I'm having trouble accessing it to populate the second viewcontroller.

First view controller where the user loads an image:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[userImageView setImage:image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

//Save the temp file
tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() isDirectory:YES];
fileURL = [[tmpDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"userPic"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"jpg"];
NSLog(@"fileURL: %@", [fileURL path]);
}
```

The question I have is, how can I call the saved file in the viewdidload of the second view controller?

I was playing around with stuff like this, but I'm getting errors (I was just wishing!):

```
userImageView.image = _fileURL;
```

`userImageView` is an outlet that I have set to my image view.

declared in the .h file of the first controller

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSURL *fileURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSURL *tmpDirURL;
```

Comment: You never save the file.  You create the URL path, but there's no writing of the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy try below steps

1.covert selected image into nsdata

2.create document directory path

3.append image name into document path

3.use  [data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
 to write last created path.

4.then wherever or wherever you want you access image from document folder

Comment: So your response has helped a lot, and I appreciate it. I am truley trying to learn, so your list has helped me do so. I am now saving the image to the documents directory (i've verified this by going into the file. I was also able to open it as a image! progress...yes!) My problem now, is that I can't find anything clear on how to access it from my documents directory. This is how it's saved:

Comment: data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userImageView.image);  
    
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];  

databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userPic.png"]];  

[data writeToFile:databasePath atomically:YES];

Comment: NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; userImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/userPic.png", path]];

Comment: anyone else looking ^ this is how i accessed the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just assign an NSURL as the image property.

It would be:

```
userImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[_fileURL absoluteString]];
```

Also, it doesn't look like you actually save the file (unless you are doing that elsewhere).  Why not just keep a pointer to the image that is picked and pass the pointer to the other view controller?

You already have a pointer to a UIImage above in the line

`image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`.

If you create a UIImage property (strong) in your second view controller, and set it to the same thing, you should still be able to use it.  For example if your second view controller is `mySecondViewController`, and it had a property called `theImageINeed`, you could do the following:

```
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[userImageView setImage:image];
mySecondViewController.theImageINeed = image;
```

However, it seems like you are presenting one view controller from the one that you need the image for.  In this case, I would ignore what I just said, and create a delegate method for this.

That means that in your presented view's header, you would have something like:

```
//In the header file of the presented view
@protocol FoundMahImageDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)userSelectedAnImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end

@interface yourViewName : NSObject

//whatever else you already have

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <FoundMahImageDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

And in the .m file:

```
//In the implementation file of the presented view
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[userImageView setImage:image];
[self.delegate userSelectedAnImage:image];  //<-- the part that changed
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

In your **presenting** view, you now have to add the protocol in the header file:

```
@interface myMainViewController : NSObject <FoundMahImageDelegate>
//...
```

And in its implementation file, add the method that we put in the protocol definition:

```
- (void)userSelectedAnImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    //here you go, you've got the image, do something with it
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had tried that, but i get incompatible pointer types "NSURL to NSString"

Comment: Then `userImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[_fileURL absoluteString]];`

Comment: I updated my answer above to match.  the absoluteString instance method returns the absolute path as an NSString.

Comment: Your right, I don't think that I am actually saving the image. What do you mean about using a pointer? Can you point me in the right direction (no pun intended)?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try this

```
userImageView.image =[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_fileURL]];
```